# Error trying to access Modules

Tags: control-panel, module

I get this error (see attached) when trying to access the 'Modules Panel'. Has anyone got any idea why this is happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the RTE module installed? Does that language file exist on the server?

Comment: Well I will go check, however it is odd cause I have not removed any files since install and my installation was running fine for months until this happened just now.

Comment: Checked and yes it was missing ... Not sure how it got removed. Thanks for your input.